# Apache Avro UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}]: 2001-01-01

Tags: avro, spring-cloud-stream

Despite examples collected here and there, I haven't been able to produce a correct **Avro 1.9.1** schema for my (lomboked) class, getting the title's error message at serialization time of my LocalDate field.
Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

```
@Data
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private LocalDate birth;
    private Integer votes = 0;
}
```

This is the schema:

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "Person",
"namespace": "com.example.demo",
"fields": [
{
    "name": "id",
    "type": "long"
},
{
    "name": "firstname",
    "type": "string"
},
{
    "name": "birth",
    "type": [ "null", { "type": "int", "logicalType": "date" }]
},
{
    "name": "votes",
    "type": "int"
}]
}
```

The error, meaning java.time.LocalDate is not found in the union's "index named" map, is this:
org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"int","logicalType":"date"}]: 2001-01-01

Index named map keys are "null" and "int", which seems logical.

Comment: I also unsuccessfully tried UNION ["null",{"type":"string","logicalType":"date"}]